# Web2py: stop guest users from changing password

Tags: passwords, web2py

I'm setting up a demo web2py site to show a few people. I'm going to set up a 'guest' account with a simple password. How can I stop someone logged in as 'guest' from changing this password, while allowing other (non-guest) users to change their password if they want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after defining the `Auth` object, you can do something like the following:

```
auth = Auth(db)
if auth.user and auth.user.username == 'guest':
    auth.settings.actions_disabled = ['reset_password', 'request_reset_password',
                                      'change_password', 'profile']
```

If login is via email address rather than username, then the second condition above would instead be `auth.user.email == guest_email_address` (fill in the actual email address of the guest account).

Comment: That's great, thanks. I guess if I allocate the guess user to a 'guest' group, can I can also do something like `if 'guest_group' in auth.user.groups:`? I couldn't find any documentation for this.